# "Resize2FS" compact data blocks before resize

Tags: linux, lvm, ext4, resize2fs

We suppose to have a partition of 100Gb filled up by 75Gb of data.

We want to reduce it by 20Gb.

- Does **resize2fs** move the 75Gb of data to the remaining 80Gb, and then resize the partition? In other words: are the data preserved?
- If yes, is that valid for [LVM](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/544913/resize-safely-root-lvm) too?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `resize2fs` moves data as needed (at least on ext4). That means that `lvreduce -r` *(the `-r` is critical)* is safe as well, because it first calls `resize2fs` via `fsadm`. Note that ext4 can shrink only in offline mode (when unmounted); trying to do it while mounted should just error out.

Of course, "safe" is only if there are no bugs, power isn't cut in the middle, etc. So you should still have backups.

BTW: roaima informs me that `resize2fs` actually syncs after each write, I presume that's to be safe in case of power failure. That'd of course depend on sync actually fully working, which it doesn't always (sometimes disk and especially SSDs do not handle power failures well). That also means that `eatmydata` (which prevents sync) can speed it up a bit — something roaima has tried — with of course making it much less safe if any failure occurs.

Comment: One of the reasons `resize2fs` is slow is that it performs a sync after every write. (Use `strace` to watch this going on.) I've used `eatmydata` on a system with a UPS to speed this up somewhat.

Comment: @roaima Interesting, possibly it is safe, then, if power is cut in the middle. At least if there are no bugs (including disk firmware or hardware ones).

Comment: Possibly, yes. I wouldn't want to be in a position of needing to find out retrospectively though.

Comment: Having a backup is always a good idea. 70GB isn't so much data these days that you couldn't make a dd or tar backup of the filesystem first.

Comment: If a backup is available, the question arises whether reformatting and restoring from backup is faster than the resize - it really depends on how much data needs to be moved from the end of the filesystem. There was a patch https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/960766/ that allowed setting a high watermark for block allocations so that you could "drain" the top of the filesystem while mounted (eg. via e4defrag), to minimize the offline time for the resize, but it was never landed.